# Using Spring MVC with CockroachDB

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, cockroachdb

I am trying to develop a Spring MVC application liked to a CockroachDB Cluster database using Hibernate with PostgreSQL driver.

The connection with the database is fine, and all tables are created.

But when I launch the server I get this error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1081) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:856) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at fr.esper.back.restfull.RestfullBackServer.main(RestfullBackServer.java:9) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:954) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:882) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353) ~[spring-orm-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:370) ~[spring-orm-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:359) ~[spring-orm-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Error accessing index information: testdb.car
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:106) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:95) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.convertSQLException(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:99) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.getIndexes(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:609) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.TableInformationImpl.indexes(TableInformationImpl.java:110) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.TableInformationImpl.getIndex(TableInformationImpl.java:121) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.findMatchingIndex(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:292) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.applyIndexes(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:277) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.doMigrationToTargets(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:184) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.doMigration(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:60) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:134) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:472) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:879) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "."
  Détail : source SQL:
SELECT NULL AS TABLE_CAT, n.nspname AS TABLE_SCHEM,   ct.relname AS TABLE_NAME, NOT i.indisunique AS NON_UNIQUE,   NULL AS INDEX_QUALIFIER, ci.relname AS INDEX_NAME,   CASE i.indisclustered     WHEN true THEN 1    ELSE CASE am.amname       WHEN 'hash' THEN 2      ELSE 3    END   END AS TYPE,   (i.keys).n AS ORDINAL_POSITION,   trim(both '"' from pg_catalog.pg_get_indexdef(ci.oid, (i.keys).n, false)) AS COLUMN_NAME,   CASE am.amcanorder     WHEN true THEN CASE i.indoption[(i.keys).n - 1] & 1       WHEN 1 THEN 'D'       ELSE 'A'     END     ELSE NULL   END AS ASC_OR_DESC,   ci.reltuples AS CARDINALITY,   ci.relpages AS PAGES,   pg_catalog.pg_get_expr(i.indpred, i.indrelid) AS FILTER_CONDITION FROM pg_catalog.pg_class ct   JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON (ct.relnamespace = n.oid)   JOIN (SELECT i.indexrelid, i.indrelid, i.indoption,           i.indisunique, i.indisclustered, i.indpred,           i.indexprs,           information_schema._pg_expandarray(i.indkey) AS keys         FROM pg_catalog.pg_index i) i     ON (ct.oid = i.indrelid)   JOIN pg_catalog.pg_class ci ON (ci.oid = i.indexrelid)   JOIN pg_catalog.pg_am am ON (ci.relam = am.oid) WHERE true  AND n.nspname = 'testdb' AND ct.relname = 'car' ORDER BY NON_UNIQUE, TYPE, INDEX_NAME, ORDINAL_POSITION 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               ^
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2412) ~[postgresql-42.0.0.jar:42.0.0]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2125) ~[postgresql-42.0.0.jar:42.0.0]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:297) ~[postgresql-42.0.0.jar:42.0.0]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:428) ~[postgresql-42.0.0.jar:42.0.0]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:354) ~[postgresql-42.0.0.jar:42.0.0]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:301) ~[postgresql-42.0.0.jar:42.0.0]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:287) ~[postgresql-42.0.0.jar:42.0.0]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:264) ~[postgresql-42.0.0.jar:42.0.0]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeQuery(PgStatement.java:231) ~[postgresql-42.0.0.jar:42.0.0]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgDatabaseMetaData.getIndexInfo(PgDatabaseMetaData.java:2325) ~[postgresql-42.0.0.jar:42.0.0]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.getIndexes(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:567) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    ... 38 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 0
```

The schema is simple: User owning multiple cars.

**Class User**

```
Entity
@Table(name = "ApplicationUser")
public class User {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    @NotNull @Column(unique = true)
    private String username;
    @NotNull @Size(min = 5, max = 15)
    private String password;
    @NotNull
    private String firstName;
    @NotNull
    private String lastName;
    @NotNull @Column(unique = true)
    private String mailAddress;
    @NotNull @Column(unique = true)
    private String phoneNumber;
...........
}
```

**Class Car**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "car",
        indexes = @Index(name = "owner_index", columnList = "owner_id"))
public class Car {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private String name;
    @OneToOne
    private User owner;
......
}
```

**Application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:postgresql://~~~~~~/testdb
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.database = postgresql
spring.datasource.driver-class-name= org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

The problem seems to come from the **index** on the foreign key "owner" in the Car table because the index of the foreign key was not created.

When I try to show indexes from Car I get:

```
~~~~~~~~~~/testdb> show indexes from car;
+-------+---------+--------+-----+--------+-----------+---------+----------+
| Table |  Name   | Unique | Seq | Column | Direction | Storing | Implicit |
+-------+---------+--------+-----+--------+-----------+---------+----------+
| car   | primary | true   |   1 | id     | ASC       | false   | false    |
+-------+---------+--------+-----+--------+-----------+---------+----------+
```

I already tried to create manually the index on the field owner_id but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

CockroachDB does not currently support all the SQL features used by Hibernate.

Looking at the failing query, the problem is accessing `(i.keys).n` where keys comes from `information_schema._pg_expandarray(i.indkey)`.

We are tracking support for Hibernate in CockroachDB [here](https://github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/issues/16491) with more specific support for `_pg_expandarray` tracked [here](https://github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/issues/16971).